# Error in Hive: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.thrift.EncodingUtils.setBit(BIZ)B

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, runtime-error, integration

After i've integrated HBase with Hive, running any query in Hive Terminal showing following Error

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.thrift.EncodingUtils.setBit(BIZ)B"
```

my environment details are as follows:

```
Hadoop-1.2.1

Hive-0.12.0

HBase-0.94.15
```

and i have followed the following steps in Integration between Hive and HBase, Correct me if i'm wrong in my deployment steps:

1) Have replaced the Following Jars in `Hive/Lib` from `HBase/lib`:

```
hbase-0.94.15.jar

hbase-0.94.15-tests.jar

guava-11.0.2.jar

zookeeper-3.4.5.jar

protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar
```

2) copy pasted all the Jar's from `HBase/Lib` to `Hadoop/lib`  folder.